# Word for intuition but with reasoning?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Can one use the word `intuition` for the following scenario:-

> Tester: (Checks output file) I think A->1 (A is being mapped to 1), because I am seeing a pattern in the input and output files that was shared by the client.
>
> Developer: But client hasn't pointed that out(to make that changes), you seem to be right though. It's still better to ask the client than making changes
>          going by your 'intuition'.

Is developer right here using the word, 'intuition'. I googled the meaning and it said

`It is based without a consious reasoning`

But one can clearly see Tester is making a consious reasoning.

So if intuition is the not the suitable word, do you have something else to suggest? If not please tell how it is right.

Comment: There is no reasoning that I can see in your example. *I am seeing a pattern* provides no explanation for anything. It's no different than *I sense something good in your future*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Tester is seeing a pattern based on the test input and output files that was shared by client earlier but in the output file produced by developer he is not seeing. But the client had not highlighted what needed to be done regarding A->1.(I have edited the question)

Comment: After all, *intuition* it is. Google harder.

Comment: All you've done is expand *seeing a pattern* into *seeing a pattern in X and Y*. That still doesn't move it from *intuition* to *reasoning*. It would be reasoning if the tester said, "*Here's what's happening. Every time A has happened in the past, B has resulted. Therefore, I reason that since A has happened this time, B should result this time.* That's reasoning. Simply saying *I see some random, unexplained pattern and so I believe B will happen* is not. Or at least it's not reasoning that's being *communicated* in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[intuition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intuition)** (ODOL)

> noun
>   [mass noun]
>   **1** The ability to understand something instinctively, without the need for conscious reasoning.

However, in practice, it is considered to be subconsciously influenced by past experience and conditioning.

WP has this to say about intuition:

> Different writers give the word "intuition" a great variety of different meanings, ranging from direct access to unconscious knowledge, unconscious cognition, inner sensing, inner insight to unconscious pattern-recognition and the ability to understand something instinctively, without the need for conscious reasoning.
>   …
>   (In modern psychology,) (d)ifferent writers give the word "intuition" a great variety of different meanings, ranging from direct access to unconscious knowledge, unconscious cognition, inner sensing, inner insight to unconscious pattern-recognition and the ability to understand something instinctively, without the need for conscious reasoning.
>   …
>   experts used their base of experience to identify similar situations and intuitively choose feasible solutions.
>   …
>   Colloquial usage: Intuition, as a gut feeling based on experience, ….

That last part about colloquial usage sums it up well.

Answer (score 0):

Presumption or Assumption would be a good word to use here since the developer is not sure whether the tester's approach / conclusion is correct or not from client's perspective, although they may be correct (they are not certain).

 [Presumption](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presumption) means "a belief that something is true because it is likely, although not certain".